# How to use Rcords to pass parameters to the queue

Tags: http, delphi, records, delphi-xe8, omnithreadlibrary

how i can pass memo lines strings to `TRecords` fields to use theme as a parameters for idHTTP POST methode?

usually id do it like this

```
for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count-1 do
begin
  P := Pos('+', Memo1.Lines.Strings[i]);
  Email:= Copy(Memo2.Lines.Strings[i], 1, P-1);
  Name:= ExtractName(Memo2.Lines.Strings[i]);
  lPOSt // HTTP POST; //Email&Name Global Var for HTTP post Params
  Sleep(1000);
 end;
```

but in pipeline pattern i have to use records , so i can pass the parameters to the queue. Or is there any way to use `Email` and `Name` as parameters for for POST method?

```
 Reply := TStringList.Create;
 Params.Add('Email=' + Email); // Email is Global Var
 Params.Add('Name=' + Name);   // Name is Global Var
 lHTTP.Post('http://www.mywebserverx.com/', Params);

type
  TRecords = record
  Name : string;
  eMail : string;
  Car: string;
end;
```

My pipeline code, using HTTP Get

```
procedure TForm2.StartButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  s       : string;
  urlList : TStrings;
begin
  urlList := Memo1.Lines;
 pipeline := Parallel.Pipeline;  
 pipeline.Stage(Retriever).NumTasks(10).Run;

// Retriever>>>idHTTP GET opertaion
//how to modify the pipeline input after using records as Params?

 for s in urlList do
  pipeline.Input.Add(s);
  pipeline.Input.CompleteAdding;
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me. Do you want to add `TRecords` to the pipeline? What should happen in the pipeline? Maybe you should add more information and/or a more complete example. I answered your question anyway as I understood it for now.

Comment: @RenéHoffmann Edited the post, i have memo contains `email+name` strings i want use these strings as parameters in my post method,  i usually separate the Email and Name using functions

Comment: @RenéHoffmann have a look here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39439950/how-to-take-the-input-string-to-the-output-of-pipeline-pattern]

Answer (score 1):

`pipeline.Input` is of type `IOmniBlockingCollection`. Method `IOmniBlockingCollection.Add` expects a parameter of type `TOmniValue`. For most types you can simply put the variable as the parameter because `TOmniValue` implements many implicit class operators. These implicit class operators do all the work for you, when the variable is not of type `TOmniValue`.

However, `TOmniValue` does not implement a implicit class operator for records. For record types, you have to cast it to `TOmniValue` yourself. Fortunately, `TOmniValue` has a generic class function for this: `TOmniValue.CastFrom<T>()`.

So, if you want to add a record of type `TRecords` (which is a bad, ambigous name, imho) you just call `pipeline.Input.Add(TOmniValue.CastFrom<TRecords>(RecordsVar)`.

**But why do you want to do all the parsing in the calling thread?**

The calling thread should just add the strings like it is currently implemented:

```
for s in urlList do
  pipeline.Input.Add(s);
pipeline.Input.CompleteAdding;
```

Let the parsing happen in the pipeline. There you can use implicit casting from `TOmniValue` to `string`.